# How to change child tag order in XML (Generated by PHP)

Tags: php, xml

I have one application in flash in which multiple users can log in and can upload images. when user log in he can view images uploaded by him and also can view images uploaded by other users(only allowed images). for that i am generating xml file through php.

**please check xml file.**

```
<images>
    <users user_name="Hardik">
        <image image_id="1316683023140" image_title="water" image_desc="water" image_path="all_users/Hardik/1316683023140.jpg" image_like="false"/>
        <image image_id="1316683057577" image_title="sunset" image_desc="sunset" image_path="all_users/Hardik/1316683057577.jpg" image_like="false"/>
        <image image_id="1316683115124" image_title="hills" image_desc="hills" image_path="all_users/Hardik/1316683115124.jpg" image_like="false"/>
        <image image_id="1316683713159" image_title="sun" image_desc="sun" image_path="all_users/Hardik/1316683713159.jpg" image_like="false"/>
        <image image_id="1316684544200" image_title="sun" image_desc="sun" image_path="all_users/Hardik/1316684544200.jpg" image_like="false"/>
        <image image_id="1316686014899" image_title="sun" image_desc="sun" image_path="all_users/Hardik/1316686014899.jpg" image_like="false"/>
        <image image_id="1316600184214" image_title="asd" image_desc="asd" image_path="all_users/Hardik/1316600184214.jpg" image_like="false"/>
        <image image_id="1316668356801" image_title="hello" image_desc="hello" image_path="all_users/Hardik/1316668356801.jpg" image_like="false"/>
        <image image_id="1316600221759" image_title="asd" image_desc="asd" image_path="all_users/Hardik/1316600221759.jpg" image_like="false"/>
        <image image_id="1316600193960" image_title="asd" image_desc="asd" image_path="all_users/Hardik/1316600193960.jpg" image_like="false"/>
        <image image_id="1316600172938" image_title="asd" image_desc="asd" image_path="all_users/Hardik/1316600172938.jpg" image_like="false"/>
        <image image_id="1316600144316" image_title="asd" image_desc="asd" image_path="all_users/Hardik/1316600144316.jpg" image_like="false"/>
        <image image_id="1316600173551" image_title="asd" image_desc="asd" image_path="all_users/Hardik/1316600173551.jpg" image_like="false"/>
        <image image_id="1316600177792" image_title="asd" image_desc="asd" image_path="all_users/Hardik/1316600177792.jpg" image_like="false"/>
        <image image_id="1316496700758" image_title="sunset" image_desc="sunset" image_path="all_users/Hardik/1316496700758.jpg" image_like="false"/>
        <image image_id="1316252181829" image_title="allow" image_desc="allow" image_path="all_users/Hardik/1316252181829.jpg" image_like="false"/>
        <image image_id="1316690195793" image_title="asasdas" image_desc="asdasd" image_path="all_users/Hardik/1316690195793.jpg" image_like="false"/>
        <image image_id="1316600153509" image_title="asd" image_desc="asd" image_path="all_users/Hardik/1316600153509.jpg" image_like="false"/>
        <image image_id="1316408901775" image_title="winter" image_desc="winter" image_path="all_users/Hardik/1316408901775.jpg" image_like="false"/>
    </users>
    <users user_name="raj">
            <image image_id="1315996252734" image_title="abc" image_desc="abc" image_path="all_users/raj/1315996252734.jpg" image_like="false"/>
    </users>
    <users user_name="sandip">
            <image image_id="1315996256153" image_title="abc" image_desc="abc" image_path="all_users/sandip/1315996256153.jpg" image_like="false"/>
    </users>
</images>
```

i have one logical issue with my XML file (that is generated by PHP). now i want to change child tag order. i want to have child tag of a user (that is logged in) in first position.

say if sandip logins his child tag should come first instead hardik.

**you can check my php code here**

```
<?php
    require_once('connection.php');

    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
    echo "<images>";

    $id='';
    $count=0;
    $result_1 = '';


    $query = "select  ui.userId as 'UI userId', ua.userName as 'UI userName', ui.imageId as 'UI ImageId', ul.imageId as 'UL ImageId' , ui.imageRights, ui.imagePath, ui.imageTitle, ui.imageDesc from user_account ua, (select * from user_images where userId=".$_REQUEST['userId']." or imageRights='Allow') as ui left join (select * from user_likes where userId=".$_REQUEST['userId'].") as ul on ui.imageId = ul.imageId where ua.userId=ui.userId order by ui.userId";

    $result_row = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_row, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
            if($id != $row['UI userId'])
            {
                if($count == 0)
                {
                    $result_1 .= "<users user_name='".$row['UI userName']."'>";
                }
                else
                {
                    $result_1 .= "</users>";
                    $result_1 .= "<users user_name='".$row['UI userName']."'>";
                }
                $id = $row['UI userId'];
            }

            $result_1 .= "<image image_id='".$row['UI ImageId']."' image_title='".$row['imageTitle']."' image_desc='".$row['imageDesc']."' image_path='".$row['imagePath']."' image_like='";

            if($row['UL ImageId'])
                $result_1 .= "true";
            else
                $result_1 .= "false";
            $result_1 .= "' />";

            $count++;

            if($count == mysql_num_rows($result_row))
                $result_1 .= "</users>";
    }

    echo $result_1;
    echo "</images>";
?>
```

if you have any better solution please forward.

Comment: if you have not any answers please do not down votes. please.

Comment: i just need help in PHP, what is the logic that i should follow so that i get XML i want.

Comment: Finally i get one answer(working perfectly) but still i am finding better answer than this.

Comment: That's when bounties come in handy dude...

Comment: [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked.

Comment: If my answer was useful to you then there's an up arrow next to it :)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest some fixes to your php script in addition to solving your problem:

```
$num_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result_row); // Don't call this every loop it's very slow
$rows = [];
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_row, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    if($id == $row['UI userId']){
        // Print the logged in user's images
    } else {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
}

// Print here the rest of the results
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if($id != $row['UI userId'])
    {
        if($count == 0)
        {
            $result_1 .= "<users user_name='".$row['UI userName']."'>";
        }
        else
        {
            $result_1 .= "</users>";
            $result_1 .= "<users user_name='".$row['UI userName']."'>";
        }
        $id = $row['UI userId'];
    }

    $result_1 .= "<image image_id='".$row['UI ImageId']."' image_title='".$row['imageTitle']."' image_desc='".$row['imageDesc']."' image_path='".$row['imagePath']."' image_like='";

    if($row['UL ImageId'])
        $result_1 .= "true";
    else
        $result_1 .= "false";
    $result_1 .= "' />";

    $count++;

    if($count == $num_of_rows)
        $result_1 .= "</users>";
}

echo $result_1;
echo "</images>";
?>
```

Comment: i am still thinking better solution than this, pls forward if you have.

Comment: How can you know that there's a better solution if you can't think of one?
There is no way other than splitting it into two loops because you don't know where the logged in user is in the result.
And why o you need a better solution?

Comment: Actually it would be possible if you would push each user tag in an array and unshift(put in first place) the logged in user's tag.